# Parsing XML with 2 "values"

Tags: xml, powershell

I try to select a value from an XML like this

```
<article>
  <attachments/>
  <technical>
    <feature classification="ETIM 5.0" code="EF000889" language="pl" value="EV000074">
      <name>Some name</name>
      <value>1234</value>
    </feature>
    <feature classification="ETIM 5.0" code="EF000881" language="pl">
      <name>Some name</name>
      <value>345</value>
      <unit>A</unit>
    </feature>
  </technical>
</article>
```

In powershell I wrote:

```
[xml]$p = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri 'https://domain.tld/file.xml'
$p.article.technical.feature | select code, value, unit
```

And this work *almost* perfect, however when a feature has its own value I am getting array like:

```
code         value              unit
EF000889     {EV000074, 1234}          
EF000881     345                A
```

Anyone have idea how to get second value?

Comment: $p.article.technical.feature.value[1]  ?

Comment: @Kayasax would that no drop the second value of the next "feature"? Perhaps the op is looking to ignore the values that are attribute based.

Comment: @Matt yes I think this is what the op wants

Comment: With such an XML the attribute `value` is merged into an array, so you can't differ value from `<tag value="bla" />` and `<tag><value>foo</value></tag>`. You can query whether `value` is an array by getting its `getType().fullName`. If it's `System.Object[]` - it's an array, you need to iterate through it to get all the values, then filter those you probably need. If it's only the second, use the code @Kayasax provided. If not, do a foreach-loop against the array and do something with each of the values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

will that work for you ?

```
$p.article.technical.feature |%{ 
    if ($_.value.gettype().fullname -eq "System.Object[]"){$_.value[1]}          
    else{$_.value}
 }
```

Comment: I'd edit the condition, `if ($_.value.gettype().fullName -eq "System.Object[]")`

Comment: @Vesper Yeah this is the property I was looking for.Thanks

Comment: Yep, that way is fine :)